# Install Russian input method on android

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, languages, localization, input-methods

I don't have Russian input method in the list of methods available. Tried third party apps like 'change locale' bu they are changing interface of the OS and not giving me to type in Russian.

Android version: 4.1.2, Device: Samsung Galaxy S2 LTE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to look at 3rd-party [keyboard replacement apps](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=russian%20keyboard&c=apps), not locale changing apps.

Many well known keyboards like [Swype](http://beta.swype.com/) and [SwiftKey](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.touchtype.swiftkey) offer Russian layouts as either an in-app downloads, or separate add-on packages (like [AnySoftKeyboard](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=anysoftkeyboard&c=apps)'s [language packs](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.anysoftkeyboard.languagepack.russian2) for example.)

Keep in mind that after the initial installation new Keyboard apps are not enabled. Go to `Settings -> Language & input`, scroll down to "Keyboards & input methods" section, tap on the checkbox of the newly installed app, and tap OK to accept the scary warning. You should now be able to switch to your new keyboard. This is for Android 4.x; on other OS versions the menus might be slightly different.

Comment: I've installed Russian keyboard app, but i have no way to deselect 'samsung keyboard' in the keyboards and input methods list (Language and input menu item in settings). So when i opening some text editor - only default keyboard is available.

Comment: After initial installation new Keyboard apps are not enabled.  Go to `Settings -> Language` & input, scroll down to "Keyboards & input methods" section, tap on the checkbox of the newly installed app, and tap `OK` to accept the scary warning.  You should now be able to switch to your new keyboard.  This is for Android 4.x, keep in mind that on other OS versions the menus might be different.

Comment: I chose to install [AnySoftKeyboard](http://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdfilter=keyboard&fdid=com.menny.android.anysoftkeyboard) (which is also available on F-Droid, which guarantees it is free/open-source, can be rebuilt from sources, and has been inspected by more people for not having spying features).

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what OS version you have but the [Hacker's Keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.pocketworkstation.pckeyboard) has a phonetic russian layout that might work for you.